# Unable to resolve dependency after deploy on artifactory

Tags: android, artifactory

After I published my library on my repository on Jfrog I can see the library but I can't use it.

[image]

When I try to implement it on my gradle file as follow:

```
implementation 'com.example.demo:xdemo:1.0'
```

I get:

> Unable to resolve dependency for
> ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
> com.example.demo:xdemo:1.0.

I have declared on root gradle file the repository:

```
maven { url "https://xxxxx.jfrog.io/artifactory/gradle-dev-local" }
```

Comment: UPDATE: I needed to add user permisions and this solved the problem

Comment: What permission have you added, how you have resolved this?